# Loadblance across kubernetes master nodes

Tags: kubernetes

Is there any documentation how to use an external load balancer to load balance traffic on kubernetes API server.

Use case:

I don't prefer to use single master node ip/name in kubeconfig file and need a common name for all of the masters so that if one master is down , it sends traffic to other.

I have DNS name already pinting to loadbalancer ip , and loadbalancer is confifured with SSL certificate and kubernetes master backend nodes , but it results in an error:
"plan http request was sent to https server "

Somehow the load balancer is sending http request to kubernetes API server instead of https.

Comment: This is most likely an issue with your load balancer and not with the API server. The answer will depend on what you are using to load balance. Can you add that information to your question and tag it for that load balancer technology?

Comment: we are using pulse secure vtm. we do ssl for many many endpoints , and it works withouts issues , there is something special about kubernetes API server , though i have added the external name to cluster SANS.

Comment: Sounds like your loadbalancer is terminating the SSL/TLS and you need to reestablish a secure connection with the api server on the backend.

Comment: @switchboard.op but the loadbalancer should be doing that automatically right, there is no additional configuration for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it doenst work on L7 http , but works fine on L4 tcp.

The HAProxy configuration looks like:

```
frontend k8s-api
  bind 192.168.0.150:443
  bind 127.0.0.1:443
  mode tcp
  option tcplog
  default_backend k8s-api

backend k8s-api
  mode tcp
  option tcplog
  option tcp-check
  balance roundrobin
  default-server inter 10s downinter 5s rise 2 fall 2 slowstart 60s maxconn 250 maxqueue 256 weight 100
  server k8s-api-1 192.168.0.147:6443 check
  server k8s-api-2 192.168.0.148:6443 check
  server k8s-api-3 192.168.0.149:6443 check
```